# Kafka Streams DSL retry logic (writing record back to topic)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When doing KStream - KTable left join i want to send the record back to the same topic if the right table doesn't match, X amount of seconds later.

Is this achievable with the DSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could to a

```java
KStream[] streams = stream.leftJoin(table,...).branch(...);
stream[1].transform(...).to("input-topic");
```

You use branch to put joined records into the first stream and non-joined records into the second stream. The second stream is piped into `transform()` that uses a state store to buffer those record, and you can send `context.forward()` them using `punctuations` with 5 second delay.